# ERROR: Functions are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs, rutas, componentes

me sale el siguiente error en mi app de ReactJS:

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
    at Productos
    at Routes 
    at Router 
    at BrowserRouter 
    at div
    at App
```

Mi codigo en la App.js es:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Navbar/> 
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<ItemListContainer greeting="Bienvenido a Vigue, confecciones textiles"/>}/>
      <Route path='/item/:id' element={<ItemDetailContainer/>}/>  
      <Route path='/category/productos' element={<Productos/>}/>
    </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

y mi codigo en el componente  es:

```
import React from "react";
const Productos = () => {
    
    return() => {
        <div class="container text-center">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/74/99/be/7499bec81482a113d1bfe61dcacfd003.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Deco"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}

export default Productos
```

(en realidad son 4 divs iguales con diferentes fotos, pero las saque para acortar cod)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En efecto, tienes mal el componente Productos.

```
import React from "react"; 

const Productos = () => {
    return () => {
      ...
    }
}
```

El return esta mal estructurado de tal forma que genera este error, esto debería ser de la siguiente forma:

```
import React from "react"; 

const Productos = () => {
    return (
      ..
    )
}
```